# Can't Run Jenkins in Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I fresh installed jenkins.

[image: Here is a screen shot]
When i try to go

> http://public-ip:8888  -> it gives error "This site can't be reached" I'm sure my port is opened and added security group.

I got another ports works with apache, should i add a config for httpd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, Jenkins listen on default port `8080` not `8888`.

So allow `8080` from SG and try with new port http://example.com:8080.

Furhter option that can help in de

- ssh to the server and do `curl localhost:8080` if responding mean server is up and running, double-check SG
- if responding on localhost, check instance is in private subnet or public subnet.

Answer (score 0):

- Run below command to get the list of all opened ports and it's PIDs.

  $netstat -tunnelp
- Get Jenkins port number and enable in Security group.

Note: If you aren't using default VPC then you have to add the PORT number to NACL as well (both Inbound and Outbound)